# file in use by another process ... while i can copy

Tags: c#, email, ioexception

I get a "***file in use by another process exception***" when creating a email and wants to add this file as attachment.

When i try to **copy** the same file to an other directory there is no problem. (state of the file is still the same)

does anybody knows whats happening here? and how i can solve this?

here is the code:

```
    public Boolean AddAttachment(string filePath, string newName = "")
    {
        try
        {               
            MimeData mime = _message.AddAttachment(filePath);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newName))
            {
                mime.FileName = newName;
            }
        return true;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            if (! AddAttachmentIfInUse(filePath, newName))
            {
                AddErrorInfo(err.Message, "AddAttachment", err.Source);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    private Boolean AddAttachmentIfInUse(string filePath, string newName = "")
    {

        byte[] data;
        string contentType = ""; 
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath); 

        try
        {

            using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                data = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            }
            // data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            MimeData mime = new MimeFactory().CreateMimeData(); 
            mime.Data = data; 
            mime.ContentType = ContentType.Parse(contentType);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newName))
            {
                mime.FileName = newName;
            }
            else{
                mime.FileName = fileName; 
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            AddErrorInfo(err.Message, "AddAttachmentIfInUse", err.Source);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Can you add some code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: It seems that your own routine opens but *not closes* the file somewhere; that's why *another process* the program you are creating. Share your code, please

Comment: Show your code please. Nobody can exactly say what is the reason only reading your description

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown? Where is the code sending the email?

Answer (score 0):

The 1st function gets the the error in _**message.AddAttachment**(..) ...

I had to change the 2nd function: do not use File.Open() but use **FileStream()** and now it's working well.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)){
        data = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(data, 0, (int)fs.Length);
```

}